# Cannot access the OSM database

Tags: php, mysql, openstreetmap

I am trying to get the speed limit using the OSM through php. But, I am unable to do that because I am getting the message as written below:

> The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.

What could be the problem? Below is my php file.
Note: the code is still incomplete, I'm for now testing if I am able to access the OSM database.. But I cant. I hope someone could point me to the right direction..

```
 <?php

$lat  = 24.32633;
$lng = 54.58061;

$latm = -0.00015 + $lat;
$latp = 0.00015 + $lat;
$lngm = -0.00015 + $lng;
$lngp = 0.00015 + $lng;

//$json_url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node(24.326180, 54.580460,24.336580, 54.580860);way(bn);(._;>;);out;';
$json_url = 'http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter';
$data = '<query type="way"> <bbox-query s="' . $lngm . '" w="' . $latm . '" n="' . $lngp . '" e="' . $latp . '"/> <!--this is auto-completed with the current map view coordinates.--> </query> <print/>';
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$result =  curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_exec($ch);

/*$resultArr = explode("<",$result);
foreach ($resultArr as $val) {
    $temp = explode('"', $val);
    //check the size of the array, if it is == 5, then do
    if ($temp[1]=="maxspeed")
        $speedlimit=$temp[3];

}

echo '{"speedlimit": "120"}'; */
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bounding box is quite small and there's simply no data available in OpenStreetMap for your bounding box. That why you get the following almost empty, but valid result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2015-06-06T08:10:03Z"/>

  <bounds minlat="54.5805" minlon="24.3262" maxlat="54.5808" maxlon="24.3265"/>


</osm>
```

I would highly recommend to try different options in overpass turbo first to get more familiar with Overpass API. Please check the following link as a starting point: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9MQ - it's also restricted to highways with a maxspeed tag (that's what you're looking for, right?).

For illustration purposes, here's a screenshot with your tiny bounding box in the middle:

[image]

Comment: Ohh! Ya, I think that would be the problem.. thanks alot mate! Will let you know after trying different co-ordinates..

Comment: Is the format correct in my query when sending the min and max lat and long?? I've given the co-ordinates [24.883968, 55.544899], with [minlong = 24.89, minlat = 24.88, maxlong = 55.54, maxlat = 55.55], but the overpass turbo doesn't seem to run it!! It takes time and never returns anything... what can be the problem :( ??

Comment: Please post a permalink to your query by clicking on "Share" in overpass turbo.

Comment: Give this one a try: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9N2 and note the sequence here: `[bbox:south,west,north,east]` - see also the documentation: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Global_bounding_box_.28bbox.29

Comment: Yess! thanksssssss alot.. I have corrected the sequence..!! works now.. thanks again alot.. this part is fine now, thankGod!